# How do I set write permissions for a directory in AWS for ec2-user?

Tags: php, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created an instance in AWS with Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo) and also install PHP on this server.

I have given permission using this command 
**chown -R apache:ec2-user /var/www/html/** and also give this permission **chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/image**
but folder is not writable this directory **/var/www/html/image**

Please suggest how can I make the image folder writable.

Comment: Please let us know what are you installing in '/var/www/html' directory. Also if you give use apache log error it would be helpful.

Comment: I have installed PHP in this directory /var/www/html and want to upload image by php code but destination folder is not writable.. I am the new  AWS .Please let me know the apache log location file so I can share the log.

Comment: This is likely to have nothing to do with AWS, this is a pure system problem. So that's why we need the error log content (sth like /var/log/httpd/errors.log), or at least the error message you get

Answer (score 4, accepted):

run this flowing command on terminal.

```
setenforce 0
nano /etc/sysconfig/selinux
SELINUX=disabled
```

Answer (score 5):

First of all check the directory permission by running the following command on terminal:

```
stat -c '%A %a %n' *
```

It will give the directory permission like:

```
-rw-r--r-- 644 \
drwxrwxr-x 775 Code Backup
drwxr-xr-x 755 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x 755 Documents
```

And again try to change the permission by sudo like:

```
sudo chown -R apache:ec2-user /var/www/html/ 
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/image
```

**Note:** you must have the rights to change the permission, that's why I added `sudo` (Super User)

Comment: I have tried the above linux command but the folder is not writable.