# Deploy Symfony Project to ec2 instance

Tags: php, symfony, caching, amazon-ec2

Having permission errors a Symfony projects var/cache dir, i made the perms 777 on dir for the sake of getting it work. i have done everything in the symfony documentation as far as i can tell. app and app_dev are both having issues on ec2, but it works fine on xampp. I did a git clone of the project to the ec2 instance and the var, cache, session are all empty on git.

Followed this
http://bryanlor.com/blog/symfony2-troubleshooting-runtimeexception-unable-create-cache-directory

Error
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to create the cache directory (/var/www/sarasoft/var/cache/prod) ' in /var/www/sarasoft/var/bootstrap.php.cache:1660

Full Stack
http://www.sarasoft.site/app.php (generate the error with stack strace)

http://www.sarasoft.site/app_dev.php (generates the same error)

Info
http://www.sarasoft.site/phpinfo.php

Server Info

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx prod]$ groups
ec2-user apache

[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx cache]$ ll -la
total 12
drwxrwxrwx+ 2 apache apache  21 Oct 14 14:23 .
drwxrwxrwx+ 5 apache apache 100 Oct 13 09:10 ..
-rwxrwxrwx+ 1 apache apache   0 Oct  8 18:26 .gitkeep

[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx var]$ getfacl cache/
# file: cache/
# owner: apache
# group: apache
user::rwx
user:root:rwx
user:apache:rwx
user:ec2-user:rwx
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::rwx
default:user::rwx
default:user:root:rwx
default:user:apache:rwx
default:user:ec2-user:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::rwx
```

Comment: Did you check what user running webserver?  Isn't is `www-data` for some reason?

Comment: Its a redhat instance so runs as apache

`apache    5536  0.0  1.5 657052 15884 ?        S    Oct16   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39845880/how-do-i-set-write-permissions-for-a-directory-in-aws-for-ec2-user 

`setenforce 0
nano /etc/sysconfig/selinux
SELINUX=disabled`